# How to generate a working jar file for my program?

Tags: java, jar, jsoup

I am rather new to java, in fact this is my first program. I seem to be having a problem with generating a jar file for my java program. It is a very basic program that merely grabs data from a website, then displays it in a gui. The program is dependent on Jsoup and HtmlCleaner. The gui was made with JFormDesigner.

Getting back to the problem, when I run the program using eclipse everything runs perfectly. No issues whatsoever. However, when I run it as an exported jar (or a jar made with Jar Maker), the GUI doesn't even show up. The strange thing is that when I run it with a `.bat` file, the GUI displays, but the program doesn't do what it is suppose to do.

I am really stuck, I am not sure what to try next. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
//package com.stackoverflow.q2835505;


import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.StringUtils;

public class TestDumper extends JFrame {
public static String test = "+";
public static String test1 = "-";
public static String itemID;
public static String stab;
public static String slash;
public static String crush;
public static String magic;
public static String range;
public static String stabDef;
public static String slashDef;
public static String crushDef;
public static String magicDef;
public static String rangeDef;
public static String Str;
public static String Prayer;
public static String lowAlch;
public static String highAlch;
public static String Name;
public boolean guiWait = false;
public static boolean printed = true;



    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        statGrabber g = new statGrabber();
        g.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        g.setVisible(true);

        for ( ; ; ) {
        while(g.test){
        String url = g.textField2.getText();
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        stab = document.select("table.wikitable.smallpadding tbody tr td").tagName("TD").eq(2).text();
        slash = document.select("table.wikitable.smallpadding tbody tr td").tagName("TD").eq(3).text();
        crush = document.select("table.wikitable.smallpadding tbody tr td").tagName("TD").eq(4).text();
        magic = document.select("table.wikitable.smallpadding tbody tr td").tagName("TD").eq(5).text();
        range = document.select("table.wikitable.smallpadding tbody tr td").tagName("TD").eq(6).text();
        stabDef = document.select("table.wikitable.smallpadding tbody tr td").tagName("TD").eq(7).text();
        slashDef = document.select("table.wikitable.smallpadding tbody tr td").tagName("TD").eq(8).text();
        crushDef = document.select("table.wikitable.smallpadding tbody tr td").tagName("TD").eq(9).text();
        magicDef = document.select("table.wikitable.smallpadding tbody tr td").tagName("TD").eq(10).text();
        rangeDef = document.select("table.wikitable.smallpadding tbody tr td").tagName("TD").eq(11).text();
        Str = document.select("table.wikitable.smallpadding tbody tr td").tagName("TD").eq(16).text();
        Prayer = document.select("table.wikitable.smallpadding tbody tr td").tagName("TD").eq(17).text();
        Name = document.select("table.wikitable.infobox caption b").text();
        highAlch = document.select("table.wikitable.infobox tbody tr td").tagName("TD").eq(8).text();
        lowAlch =  document.select("table.wikitable.infobox tbody tr td").tagName("TD").eq(9).text();
        g.sweet = true;
       // String shopPrice = document.select("table.wikitable.infobox tbody tr td").tagName("TD").eq(11).text();


       if(stab.startsWith(test)){
           stab = stab.substring(1);
       }
       if(slash.startsWith(test)){
           slash = slash.substring(1);
       }
       if(crush.startsWith(test)){
           crush = crush.substring(1);
       }
       if(magic.startsWith(test)){
           magic.trim();
           magic = magic.substring(1);
       }
       if(range.startsWith(test)){
           range.trim();
           range = range.substring(1);
       }
       if(stabDef.startsWith(test)){
           stabDef = stabDef.substring(1);
       }
       if(slashDef.startsWith(test)){
           slashDef = slashDef.substring(1);
       }
       if(crushDef.startsWith(test)){
           crushDef = crushDef.substring(1);
       }
       if(magicDef.startsWith(test)){
           magicDef.trim();
           magicDef = magicDef.substring(1);
       }
       if(rangeDef.startsWith(test)){
           rangeDef.trim();
           rangeDef = rangeDef.substring(1);
       }
       if(Str.startsWith(test)){
           Str.trim();
           Str = Str.substring(1);
       }
       if(Prayer.startsWith(test)){
           Prayer.trim();
           Prayer = Prayer.substring(1);
       }


       if(highAlch.equalsIgnoreCase("Cannot be alchemised")){
           highAlch = "0";
           lowAlch = "0";
       }
       else{
           highAlch = highAlch.replace(",", "");
           highAlch = highAlch.replace(" ", "");
           highAlch = highAlch.replace("c", "");
           highAlch = highAlch.replace("o", "");
           highAlch = highAlch.replace("i", "");
           highAlch = highAlch.replace("n", "");
           highAlch = highAlch.replace("s", "");

           lowAlch = lowAlch.replace(",", "");
           lowAlch = lowAlch.replace(" ", "");
           lowAlch = lowAlch.replace("c", "");
           lowAlch = lowAlch.replace("o", "");
           lowAlch = lowAlch.replace("i", "");
           lowAlch = lowAlch.replace("n", "");
           lowAlch = lowAlch.replace("s", "");
       }

       while(printed){
        System.out.print("item = "+ itemID+"\t");
        System.out.print(Name.replace(" ", "_")+"\t");
        System.out.print(Name.replace(" ", "_")+"\t");
        System.out.print(highAlch+"\t");
        System.out.print(lowAlch+"\t");
        System.out.print("0\t");
        System.out.print(stab+"\t");
        System.out.print(slash+"\t");
        System.out.print(crush+"\t");
        System.out.print(magic+"\t");
        System.out.print(range+"\t");
        System.out.print(stabDef+"\t");
        System.out.print(slashDef+"\t");
        System.out.print(crushDef+"\t");
        System.out.print(magicDef+"\t");
        System.out.print(rangeDef+"\t");
        System.out.print(Str+"\t");
        System.out.print(Prayer+"\n");
        System.out.print("Connected!\n");
        printed = false;
       }
        }
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: are you getting any errors / exceptions? My hunch is that you aren't including the Jsoup dependency when exporting as a jar.... in Eclipse you can do File/Export.../Java/Runnable jar file but you may need to play with the config to ensure that you include the dependencies.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588313/why-does-my-jar-file-raise-exceptions-even-if-my-program-runs-without-exception/10588459#10588459) is a very similar question.

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse, you can right click on project name

- select export
- in Java categories select Runable JAR file
- select the configuration of main class (if it not found, you should run your app before)
- set export destination
- select copy require libs in to sub-folder
- finish

Answer (score 0):

When you export a jar, you can specify dependency jars as Class-Path entry in jar manifest.mf file.  You can find more details about this in this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html.  Once you have dont this make sure respective dependent jars will be in classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eclipse IDE to generate .jar files. Also you are able to add your resource files such as images or media files into .jar .